# exclude hover from trigger for parents' child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/x01heLm2/

I want the mini thumbnail to still appear when I hover from `.box` (goal no.1) but I do not want to trigger the hover event if the user hover over the click area (goal no.2). I bind the hover event to the parent, which is `.box`, which achieved goal no.1 but stuck to achieve goal no.2.

How to not trigger the hover event if the user hover over the click area first?

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.box').not('.box .box-lower').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
           "margin-top": "+=108px"
         }, "normal");
         $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
           opacity: 1,
           'transition': 'opacity 0.3s ease 0.35s'
         });
       }, function() {
         $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).css({
           'margin-top': '92px'
         });
         $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
           opacity: 0,
           'transition': 'none'
         });
       });
     });
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 290px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #000
}
.orange {
  background: orange
}
.box-lower {
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
}
.box-upper {
  position: absolute;
}
.productsThumbWrap {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 92px;
}
.productsThumbWrap img {
  padding: 14px 6px;
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
}
.click {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-upper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/398x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="productsThumbWrap">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
    </div>
    <div class="box-lower">
      <button class="click">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no way to trigger the click area first, since it's padded inside. So, before entering the click area, you already triggered the hover on the parent. Why not use css only for this?

Comment: Do you want the expanded view to still be expanded if you move the mouse (while expanded) down to the button? Or should it un-expand by that?

Comment: Why does the click area need to be a child of the box? And when one moves the mouse to the click area the click area would move to where .productsThumbWrap is located, in other words it would be hard to click ... unless the hover was only active on box-upper. Then moving the mouse to the thumbs would move the click area under the mouse.

Comment: @Snellface if the mouse enter from above, yes keep the button, but if hover into the button first, don't expand..

Comment: @Wayne if the mouse enter from above to the button, keep the expandable elements expanded, but if user hovers into the button first, don't trigger the hover.

Comment: Then i have posted a solution for you below, i have changed which event you use however, since mouseenter and mouseleave will make this easier to perform, is there any reason why you want to use hover instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i want to make it easy for me, i would add a wrapper around the "hover to expand" bit
(View the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ncbrr6py/ )

```
<div class="hoverExpand">
</div>
```

around the "hover to expand" section giving you:

```
<div class="hoverExpand">
    <div class="box-upper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/398x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="productsThumbWrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hoverExpand').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).animate({
            "margin-top": "+=108px"
        }, "normal");
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
            opacity: 1,
            'transition': 'opacity 0.3s ease 0.35s'
        });
    });
    $('.box').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap').stop(true, true).css({
            'margin-top': '92px'
        });
        $(this).find('.productsThumbWrap img').stop(true, true).css({
            opacity: 0,
            'transition': 'none'
        });
    });
});
```

Note that it now users mouse enter and mouseleave instead, this might not be what you want, but as far as i know thy will work the same (eg: will trigger even if you alt-tab your way into the browser and your cursor "ends up" in the expander area)

i also added some css:

```
.hoverExpand{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and this will solve some issues with boxes being displayed weirdly (is this why you had the border around the entire control?).

If you wish for the expander to shrink when the user hovers the button then you should bind the mouseleave to .hoverExpander as well, but this will make it rather awkward to click the button as it will "run away" from the cursor while it shrinks back down.

There is also another alternative, if you pass event as an argument to your event handlers you can do event.stopPropagation() to stop the events from bubbling/propagating the DOM tree, and you would bind an event to whatever should stop the bubbling:

```
$('.box-lower').hover(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

if you run your old code, it will however still trigger the expansion when you hover the border or just below the button where you have some padding... (this is why adding a container instead makes it a whole lot easier..)

Comment: why use mouseenter and leave instead of hover?

Comment: Easier to program, since i have 2 different triggers, one for expanding, and one for un-expanding. This can probably be achieved with hover as well, but since you want to keep showing the smaller images if they are already visible when you hover the button, but don't want to show them when you hover the button when they are not already visible the states can be either described as "Show expanded stuff when you hover anything, but not if you hover the button and stuff is not already expanded", or "Show expanded stuff when you hover the image area, hide things when you leave the control area"

Comment: If you want to use hover then you will also have to keep track of where you are hovering, since hovering the button does different things depending on if you are showing the smaller images or not already. Thats why i think it is easier to describe it (and program) as "enter area which should expand -> expand, leave while control (area that triggers expand + button) -> hide stuff".

Comment: It's also an old habit from programming desktop application where hover was defined as the mouse being stationary for a while inside a control, much like the tool-tips you see if you hover your profile in the upper right corner of this site (in this case, it's your username). If you wanted something to happen as soon as you moved the cursor into your control you had to bind either the mouse enter event, or the mouse move event on that control.

Comment: when I hover onto the button from .box, will the expanded element there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62130/discussion-between-user3522892-and-snellface).